# Using generics for strongly typed event handlers?

Tags: c#, templates, generics, types, parameters

I am trying to implement something along the lines of

```
class Receiver {
    public RegisterEvent<T>(???);
}

class EventTypeClass {
    ...
}

class MyApp
{
    public MyApp()
    {
        RegisterEvent<EventTypeClass>(MyEventHandler);
    }

    void MyEventHandler(EventTypeClass param)
    {
        // Handle event of type 'EventTypeClass'
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I can pass a strongly typed event handler as a parameter or if it is possible at all, or am I forced to use something like

```
void MyEventHandler(object param)
{
    var castedParam = param as EventTypeClass;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass the generic type to the argument.. like this:

```
class Receiver {
    public RegisterEvent<T>(T param);
}
```

The `T` in the argument list must match the type provided into the call.

EDIT: Having re-read the question.. perhaps this is actually what you meant:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler<T>(T param);
public void RegisterEvent<T>(CustomEventHandler<T> eh) {

}
```

..same philosophy though.

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I was going for (the one in the edit). However, I forgot an integral part of the whole deal. In the RegisterEvent<T> method, can I store the event handlers in a dictionary or something? Given there are potentially infinite amount of different events that the class will trigger, I will need to keep the registered handlers/events stored somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the RegisterEvent method to take a generic delegate:

```
delegate void EventHandlerDelegate< ClassType >( ClassType p );
class Receiver
{
    public RegisterEvent< T >( EventHandlerDelegate< T > callback );
}
```

Which would also mean your calling code need not explicitly provide the type to "close" the generic method:

```
receiver.RegisterEvent( MyEventHandler );
```

---

It raises the question of why you're not just using events though....

Comment: The normal implementation of events is severely broken with regard to contravariant delegates, it includes no means by which an event publisher can ask a subscription whether the subscriber is still interested, and includes no guaranteed-threadsafe means by which a subscriber that discovers, while running on one thread, that it no longer needs an event it subscribed on another, can notify the publisher of that.  All those things can be fixed with customer implementations of the Observer Pattern.