# Genericly typed event handler in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, event-handling, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a generic event handler system that ensures type-safe usage. It shouldn't be possible to subscribe to wrong event types (like `this.on('FooEvent', (event : BarEvent) => ...)` not allowed).

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
interface Event {
    type: string;
}
type EventType<T extends Event> = T['type'];
type EventHandler<T extends Event> = (event: T) => void;

class TypedEventHandler<TEvent extends Event> {
    private eventHandlers = new Map<
        EventType<TEvent>,
        EventHandler<TEvent>[]
    >();

    on<TOnEvent extends TEvent, TOnType extends TOnEvent['type']>(
        type: TOnType,
        handler: EventHandler<TOnEvent>,
    ) {
        if (!this.eventHandlers.has(type)) {
            this.eventHandlers.set(type, []);
        }

        this.eventHandlers.get(type)!.push(handler);
    }

    emit(event: TEvent) {
        const handlers = this.eventHandlers.get(event.type);
        if (!handlers) return;

        handlers.forEach(handler => handler(event));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `.push(handler)` fails with `Argument of type 'EventHandler<TOnEvent>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<TEvent>'`. Is it possible to make the type of `eventHandlers` variable more specific, so the handler can be assigned?

I found [similar questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674630/using-generics-for-strongly-typed-event-handlers), however none that really answers my question.

Comment: Here's how to use the `TypedEventHandler`:

```typescript
interface MyEventA extends Event {
    type: 'MyEventA';
}

interface MyEventB extends Event {
    type: 'MyEventB';
    foo3: number;
}

type MyEvent = MyEventA | MyEventB;

export default class SomeClass extends TypedEventHandler<MyEvent> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addEventHandler('MyEventB', this.handler.bind(this));
    }

    handler(event: MyEventB) { // MyEventA is error
        // ...
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.emit({ type: 'MyEventB', foo3: 42 });
    }
}
```